# c# How to properly pass HttpRequestMessage in and return HttpRequestMessage out of function without leaks

Tags: c#, http, memory-management, resource-management

I'm trying to implement a rest api client in c#. I've created every requests roughly like so:

```
public async Task<string> CallCreateJob()
{
    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage =
        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL))
    
    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("some content");

    var getRequestResponse = await RunCallWithAuth(requestMessage);
    string rawResponse = await getRequestResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return rawResponse;
}
```

But the important thing is that I would like to wrap around the call with authentication like so:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunCallWithAuth(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
{
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("token", getToken()); //Token assumed to be available.
    HttpResponseMessage firstResponse= await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    
    if(firstResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {

         if (Refresh()) { //updates token in getToken() call.
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("token", getToken());
            HttpResponseMessage secondResponse = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            if(secondResponse .StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                return secondResponse;
            else
                throw new IOException("Could not authenticate");
        }
        else
            throw new IOException("Could not authenticate");
    } else{
        return firstResponse;
    }
}
```

The part that I'm nervous about is when I pass a `HttpRequestMessage` in a function and return a `HttpResponseMessage` object from my function. Since reading up on `HttpResponseMessage` it seems good practice to use either a `using` statement or use `Dispose` when I don't need it anymore. But I don't know what standard c# does when returning an object. Will it move? Or copy? Is there a way to be sure all resources in `HttpResponseMessage` are properly handled? Same questions apply for passing an object into a function. Are there standard practices on how to do this with http messages?

Comment: if you're method returns an instance of IDisposable (which it does here) then its up to the caller to handle disposing it, the method loses all control once its returns it back. There is no special handling c# does when returning an object

Comment: But it's still the same object, right? So all I have to do is dispose in the upper function?

Answer (score 2):

You can just dispose it in the calling function when you're done with it

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL))
using (var response = await RunCallWithAuth(request))
{
   // do stuff with the response here
}
```

Once you return an IDisposable from a function, it then becomes the responsibility of the caller really